# Floating point exception, need help identifying where the problem lies

Tags: c, exception

This function should print the averages of the odd and even inputs given from the while loop until 0 is entered, then it ends. It currently is not runnable, I split this block off from a larger section of code that had no correlation to the error. Any ideas where it would be giving the point exception error?

```
 int main()
{
    int numReturn;
    int evenTotal;
    int evenCount;
    int oddTotal;
    int oddCount;
    
    while(numReturn != 0){
      printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
      scanf("%d",&numReturn);
      
      if(numReturn<0){
          printf("That's a negative number!\n");
      }else if(numReturn%2 == 0){
          evenTotal += numReturn;
          evenCount += 1;
      }else{
          oddTotal += numReturn;
          oddCount += 1;
      }
    }

    double evenAvg = evenTotal/evenCount;
    double oddAvg = oddTotal/oddCount;
    
    printf("%d even numbers were entered and the average is %lf\n",evenCount,evenAvg);
    printf("%d odd numbers were entered and the average is %lf\n",oddCount,oddAvg);

   //some code for problem 1
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have to convert `int` to `double` before division: `double evenAvg = (double)evenTotal/evenCount;`

Comment: You have a bunch of uninitialized variables so they start with an indeterminate value. There's no check for possible divide by zero before calculating the averages.

Comment: When asked to add information to a question, edit the post in place. Do not post a duplicate.

Comment: Do `while (1) {` and after the `scanf` do `if (numReturn == 0) break;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int numReturn;
```

This variable is not initialized and your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Same problem with other variables.

```
    int numReturn = 1;
    int evenTotal = 0;
    int evenCount = 0;
    int oddTotal = 0;
    int oddCount= 0;
```

Also add check to make sure that you will not divide by zero (cast is needed as otherwise your will do the integer division):

```
    double evenAvg = eventCount ? (double)evenTotal/evenCount : 0.0;
    double oddAvg = oddTotal ? (double)oddTotal/oddCount : 0.0;
```

Also do use `%f` format as it is for printing `double` numbers.

Comment: Are they not initialized? They are defined and have a value, explain more please and thank you.